# Is there a better way to use multiprocessing within a loop?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm quite new to using `multiprocessing` and I'm trying to figure out if there is a better way to use `multiprocessing` when it has to be within a loop. Or at least I think it has to be within a loop. Let me try to describe the outline and then a better solution may be obvious.

I'm processing large spatial datasets with lots of data points. I'm trying to calculate values for smaller sub-regions of the large dataset by splitting it up with a regular grid. Each grid calculation can be calculated independently of another so this makes it perfect for parallel processing - I just need to know what data to send to each grid. Typically, there will be 1000's of the smaller grid-bins.

However, I'm trying to track these changes over time so I'm then repeating the same process for each timestep of data. Typically there will be 10-500 timesteps of data to process. Each timestep's data is stored in a several files on disk that I have to load when processing the timestep.

Currently my code looks a bit like the following psuedo-code and it takes about 30-60s to process a timestep. Reading and binning probably only takes a few seconds of that time and the rest is the multi-processing of each bin.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

for t in range(num_timeteps_to_process):

    # read data files for this timestep
    data_1 = read_file1_data(path, t)
    data_2 = read_file2_data(path, t)
    data_3 = read_file3_data(path, t)

    # find what data is in each grid_bin - returns data and bin_id
    binned_data = spatial_binning_function(data_1, num_bins_x=100, num_bins_y=100)


    # loop through all bins doing calculation
    bin_calc_arg_list = []

    for bin_indx, data_id in enumerate(binned_data):
        bin_calc_arg_list.append((bin_indx, data_id, data_1, data_2, data_3, other_settings))

        print("        Running Multiprocessing Pool")

        # create the process pool - multiprocessing
        with Pool(processes=num_processors) as pool:
            # execute a task
            results = pool.starmap(multiprocess_timesteps_bins, bin_calc_arg_list)

            # close the process pool
            pool.close()

            # wait for issued tasks to complete
            pool.join()

        # collate results here and return
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

`Data_1`, `Data_2` and `Data_3` are large `numpy` arrays of size n x 12, where n is typically larger than 200,000.

Each call to the `multiprocess_timesteps_bins` function returns a tuple of a unique bin_id and a list of 30 different calculated properties for the bin. `results` is then added to a dictionary with the timestep as the key.

That's the general flow of my code and it's quite a bit quicker than any single-threaded implementation but I'm aware that the opening and closing of the processing pool within each timestep loop is probably a really bad idea but the reading and subdivision of data needs to be done per timestep as I don't think running multiple processes where each one is reading the same data a few thousand times is better.

From a few print statements it seems that there may be several seconds required starting up the pool each timestep and maybe some more time spent shutting it down.

As I said, I'm not overly familiar with multiprocessing yet so I'm not quite sure what is the best way to set up a problem like this - I'm assuming my implementation is not how it should be done, but it works and it's faster than single threaded.

Should I be using some other dynamic queue that I open at the start and then pop items into that queue during each timestep? And then close once at the end?

I think what I want to do is this - move the pool creating outside the loop, read the data and then use starmap to call multiple processors to processes the bins, and because starmap is a blocking call I can just process the results before restarting the loop, while keeping the pool open.

Only close and join when I'm finished this part of the code.

This will save a lot of time for starting and shutting down the pool each timestep when using the context manager ad should be ok to use like that?

Any pointers or suggestions welcome.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I've added a description of the input and output data. The inputs are large `numpy` arrays for the raw data. The output shouldn't really matter I think, it's just collected in the pool results and then I do a little tidying and pass into a dictionary for look up at a later time.

Comment: AFAIK, you do not need `pool.close()` because this is the purpose of the `with` statement. Moreover, `pool.join()` is called after `pool.close()` which does not make sense.

Comment: Since creating a process is quite expensive on some platforms, it may be better to call `starmap` and then wait for all the task to be completed without restarting processes. But this is dependent of the duration of the tasks. If the task last a long time (e.g. few seconds or more), then I think this is not really a problem. Btw, I expect the computation to be rather memory-bound due to Numpy (so it should not scale well because of that).